# How make jcomponents change its sizes according to the screen resolution

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jframe, netbeans-8

I've created an application using jframes and jinternal frames. i wanted to make custom close and minimize buttons so i made the jframe decorated. and made it to fit the screen of a given resolution using the below codes.

```
public Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();   
public Rectangle winSize = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getMaximumWindowBounds();
public int taskBarHeight = screenSize.height - winSize.height;                public int width = (int) screenSize.getWidth();
public int height = (int) screenSize.getHeight()-taskBarHeight;
```

in the constructor ive typed

```
this.setSize(width, height);
```

and by this way i managed to make the decorated jframe to fit the screen.
now i want to make all the other components in side the jframe to change its sizes according to the screen resolution.Is there a way to make the components change their sizes, instead of assigning dimensions to each any every components separately.
i.e

```
 jDesktopPane1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width*9/10, height*88/100));
```

i found it difficult to arrange my components according to the way i wanted. so i didnt pay much attention to layouts.

Comment: Use an appropriate set of layout mangers based on your needs

Comment: i did but when ever i change them the whole thing become a mess. i mean all the components goes here and there.

Comment: Well, layout managers are the way to go, but since we have nothing to go by, that's the best I can suggest

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).